# CollectionType extension with return Type Self instead of Array

Tags: swift, generics

The `CollectionType` methods are all functional and the ones that return a collection all return an array.

Is it possible to create a generic function that implements a `map` / `forEach` like function but has a return type of `Self`?

```
extension CollectionType {

    func otherMap(block: Generator.Element -> Generator.Element) -> Self {

        var copy = self

        copy.forEach {
            $0 = block($0) // this obviously fails since $0 is immutable 
        }

        return copy
    }   
}
```

---

**Update :**

Can this be unified?
(func name says mutate even when it doesn't, I know ;))

```
extension Set {

    func mutateCollection(block: Generator.Element -> Generator.Element) -> Set {

        var copy : Set<Element> = []

        for element in self {
            copy.insert(block(element))
        }

        return copy
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Dictionary {

    func mutateCollection(block: Generator.Element -> Generator.Element) -> Dictionary {

        var copy : [Key:Value] = [:]

        for keyValuePair in self {

            let key = keyValuePair.0
            let value = keyValuePair.1

            let blockResult = block(key, value)
            copy[blockResult.0] = blockResult.1

        }
        return copy
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Array {

    func mutateCollection(block: Generator.Element -> Generator.Element) -> Array {

        var copy : [Element] = []

        for element in self {
            copy.append(block(element))
        }
        return copy
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no promise that an arbitrary `CollectionType` can be instantiated or copied. So there's no way to implement your extension. A good way to see this is to try to implement this for `FlattenCollection` or `LazyCollection`. Or try creating a `RandomValueCollection` and then try to implement this method.

But you're free to do this on a `RangeReplaceableCollectionType`, which makes all the promises you need:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollectionType {
    func otherMap(block: Generator.Element -> Generator.Element) -> Self {
        var copy = Self.dynamicType.init()
        self.forEach {
            copy.append(block($0))
        }
        return copy
    }   
}
```

Not all collections conform to `RangeReplaceableCollectionType`. There probably is a good reason `Set` doesn't, so you may have to create a simpler protocol of your own.

Remember, a `CollectionType` may represent some static thing that isn't meaningful or safe to copy. For example, I might make a `CollectionType` that represents "the files on this disk." Copying it could invalidate invariants (such as assumptions about caches and file pointers). There's no promise that a `CollectionType` is a value type. It is free to be a reference.

Comment: not entirely true, all collectiontypes can be copied. So if there was some mutating func, this would be possible.

Comment: I was just thinking about implementing this on `MutableCollectionType`, but that still doesn't promise you can construct one. Why do you say "all collectiontypes can be copied?" (assuming we both mean "to Self" here, not "to AnyCollection")

Comment: Yes, you can do `var copy = self` but you can't construct a MutableCollectionType or a CollectionType. At least not without some constraint to a `protocol` with a known `init`

Comment: Right, but `var copy = self` may not actually copy the collection. If it's a reference type, you'll mutate the original. (maybe you meant this)

Comment: Haven't checked yet, but aren't all CollectionTypes structs in Swift? I am just ignoring the existence of NSArray and the likes for the moment.

Comment: You can't ignore the existence of `NSArray`. There is no promise that all legal CollectionTypes are structs. When you write an extension, you're writing it to every possible implementation, not just the ones in stdlib today.

Comment: I know, but sometimes it helps to simplify the problem. There is no `append` / `insert` method shared between all CollectionTypes. So the entire point is mute anyway :)

Comment: Fixed; forgot about `RangeReplaceableCollectionType`. I knew that protocol had to exist…

Comment: Which xcode / swift version are you using? Mine keeps telling me to remove `dynamicType` (7.1.1)

Comment: Xcode 7.2. Just updated today. Writing this code did crash the compiler a bunch, but it does seem to work.

Comment: Includes Swift 2.1.1 :) has an extra version identifier. Braces yourselves, the tags are coming